# Finding first negative values and repacing with last non zero values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
          hrs          running_hrs  
0     203.889578           24  
1     155.929832           24  
2     180.248357           24  
3     112.502220           24  
4     102.261148           24  
5      86.982634           24  
6      35.552699           24  
7      29.260349           24  
8      0.577342            24  
9     -23.297091            0  
10    -42.875767            0  
11    -77.278587            0
```

I have to search for the first negative value from the hrs column and replace the running_hrs with the last non zero value of the hrs column.

Expected output:

```
          hrs          running_hrs  
0     203.889578           24  
1     155.929832           24  
2     180.248357           24  
3     112.502220           24  
4     102.261148           24  
5      86.982634           24  
6      35.552699           24  
7      29.260349           24  
8      0.577342            24  
9     -23.297091        0.577342  
10    -42.875767            0  
11    -77.278587            0
```

I tried finding the negative values but all negative values were selected.

Can anybody suggest the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the first element lesser than 0 with `lt` + `idxmax` -

```
i = df.hrs.lt(0).idxmax()
```

Perform indexing and assignment with `loc` -

```
df.loc[i, 'running_hrs'] = df.loc[i - 1, 'hrs']
df

           hrs  running_hrs
0   203.889578    24.000000
1   155.929832    24.000000
2   180.248357    24.000000
3   112.502220    24.000000
4   102.261148    24.000000
5    86.982634    24.000000
6    35.552699    24.000000
7    29.260349    24.000000
8     0.577342    24.000000
9   -23.297091     0.577342
10  -42.875767     0.000000
11  -77.278587     0.000000
```

---

If required, ensure that `i` is greater than `0` before assigning -

```
if i > 0:
    df.loc[i, 'running_hrs'] = df.loc[i - 1, 'hrs']
```

Otherwise, you might run into indexing errors.